# Android Apps for Smart Phones & Tablets

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a new android developer and currently creating a wallpaper app that is meant for smart phones only. The size of the images used in the app is 480x800 px.

How can I configure the app settings so that the app can be enjoyed by tablet users as well?

What settings do I need to provide in the app so that it can work on both smart phones as well as tablets. I can increase the pictures pixel say 600x1000 but internal app settings I'm not aware of. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the docs.

**Supporting Multiple Screens**

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html

**Tablet App Quality Checklist**

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

**Supporting Tablets and Handsets**

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to create xml layout to values-sw600dp as same as in res/layout folder.